# How to connect to PostgreSQL using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, ubuntu, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to my PostgreSQL database using SLQAlchemy. I have installed psycopg2 and tried to connect to database with a raw python code and it worked but this time I am trying using SQLAlchemy. I read the documentation from [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html). This might look very simple and I could not find a solution in the internet either for this specific one.
This is my code, so simple:

```
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://nysa:mypassword@127.0.0.1:46015/nysa') 
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

connection = engine.connect() 
result = connection.execute('select*from table') 
print(result)
```

When running the *.py file nothing happens and there are no errors and I tried to find the issue with pycharm's debugger and I noticed that in the line `connection = engine.connect()` gets stuck like in a infinite loop. I am pretty sure that my database credentials are correct. How do I connect to database?

Answer (score 2):

Got it. When I opening pgAdmin it shows a different port and I thought that I had to put that port in the code, that is why It did not work. Worked with `127.0.0.1:5432`.